# Generic container without stdlib

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to figure out how to create generic container using C++ without stdlib (gcc -nostdlib -nostartfiles). I've firstly encountered such problem, I even can't think how could I do it. I need something like std::vector manually, without "operator new". Could anyone give me little source with only append(), at() and remove() functions? Thank you!

Regards.

Comment: You should be able to use `std::vector` with an allocator that uses `malloc`/`free` underneath... the higher cost is building the allocator, but that is not really hard

Comment: Can you write something yourself that mimics [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: What's the purpose of doing so... A working compiler is supposed to support basic functionalities like `malloc()`, `free()` and STL.

Comment: With a problem with unusual constraints, it is helpful to describe the source and the detail of the constraints. Why do you not have stdlib? Are you literally linking with those options? Is this an intellectual excercise, or are you targeting some environment where they are not available? As we discover more details of the problem, our answers become more relevant.

Comment: why are you reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Forgot to mention, the system where I'm writing doesn't have stdlib  like Rob said. for the sake of simplicity, I'll use something-like VirtualAlloc function on Windows.
@Alex, there are things, where you have to reinvent the wheel :-)

Comment: Let's assume we're on Windows and don't want to use libstdc++ nor msvcrt lib. That's the problem. I'm trying to create std::vector like container class somehow but I honestly don't have an idea how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume you should take std::vector as your guideline (if you're looking for a dynamic container) or std::array.

I would also assume you're looking at complete memory management (which is platform specific, so here's an issue for you if you don't want any C++ memory operators), a templated class (again, use std::vector as your guideline).

You would be looking at a variety of constructors, operators, iterators, etc, much on which you can find invaluable information on [Design Patterns](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/patterns/0201633612) or stackoverflow.

**Append** for instance, implies that you allocate extra memory sequentially, so as to have a continuous block (again, platform dependant?).

**At** would have to use some form of bookkeeping or indexing, with boundary and memory checks.

**Remove** one of the same as append.

Hope this is of any help to you.

**EDIT: To answer your comment.**

using templates (such as std::vector does) you need not be concerned with the type, its the Class's(or Type's) responsibility to manage its memory.

What you could for example do in Win32, is:

```
 template<class _Ty>
 class w32Allocator
 {
     // deallocate object at _Ptr, ignore size
     void deallocate(pointer _Ptr, size_type) 
     {
         VirtualFree(_Ptr, 0, MEM_FREE);
     }

     // allocate array of _Count elements
     pointer allocate(size_type _Count)
     {
         return (pointer)VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(_Ty) * _Count, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
     }
};
```

Note: The above code is not mine, don't know if its buggy. Taken from [this post](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/977783.flat).
In this case, you are managing the low level C calls to Win32 Heap management.
Bear in mind this is tricky territory.

Then you need to worry only about an array of type _Ty, i.e. if its a continuous array (non-dynamic):

`_Ty array[number_of_objects];`

Alternatively, you can look at linked lists (where each node has a pointer to your object, and a pointer to the next node), but this may brake the continuous memory performance.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But with using of templates, I don't know where to store my custom created class, for instance:
MyClass a;
DynamicContainer b;
b.append(a); // where should I store it? as char * array or MyClass array? as I'm guessing, I have problem with pointers and references, where and how to store them. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The first stop is to implement the various memory management operators, possibly in terms of `malloc()` and `free()` (if you can't use these operators, either, things become a lot more interesting):

```
void* operator new(std::size_t size) {
    return malloc(size);
}
void* operator new[](std::size_t size) {
    return malloc(size);
}
void operator delete(void* ptr) {
    free(ptr);
}
void operator delete[](void* ptr) {
    free(ptr);
}
```

Once you got these, you can just start allocating memory as normal. Writing a `std::vector<T>` even with the small set of operations you asked for should be a simple exercise. Note, however, that using `at()` is a Bad Idea: wide interfaces glossing over errors are generally more of a problem than a solution.

Comment: "The first stop" sounds like a Freudian slip ;) `mallocl` is just a typo, I guess.

Comment: Note that `-nostdlib` means no `malloc()`, no `free()`.

Comment: Added comment to previous post, check that out, thanks.

Comment: As long as you have something resembling `malloc()` and `free()`, it should be straight forward to implement basic memory management. That's the first thing I'd create. Much of the standard library doesn't require anything beyond that and a custom clone shouldn't have more requirements. Looking at `VirtualAlloc()` or similar functionality in POSIX (e.g. `sbrk()` or `mmap()`) may require a bit book-keep for which a global object may be sufficient. Alternatively, you might want to look at allocators but it sounds like overkill